# Docker stack deploy with compose-file results in invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am trying to deploy my containers and getting this error (from `docker stack ps testapp --no-trunc`) : `invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/john/valet/testapp` .
I am using `docker-compose`. I understand that before deployment it makes my relative volume mappings into absolute ones and on the remote host the `/home/john/valet/testapp` doesn't exist.

```
  volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/:cached
```

but I am not really sure how to resolve this.

P.S. Locally everything works great with `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d` and on docker hub, my auto builds are also successfully building.

<strike>**Edited** : Just in case adding repo of the source code: https://github.com/neorganic/dockertest</strike>

Comment: you are using `/home/john/valet/testapp` in remote docker-compose file. or might be permission issue `invalid mount config for type "bind": bind mount source path does not exist: <some path> means the filesystem isn't successfully shared into the docker container.`

Comment: @Adiii Ok, but how not to use that path?  as I am nowhere setting the `/home/john/valet/testapp ` path. I am now setting a dynamic path `$PWD:/var/www/:cached`

Comment: try to run with docker run command to debug the issue, docker is allowed to acces to $PWD location?

Comment: @Adiii Will test, but just FYI added a source code link - may be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the actual problem was the fact that I didn't understand that the volume must exist on the host I am deploying the containers. For some reason, I thought it was being copied/synchronized from my local device.

I also came to conclusion that the complexity of getting your source code to host in `docker-swarm` is something that I would rather not have when `kubernetes` have this solved, so I am switching to `kubernetes` (and `gc` for that matter).

Comment: That was my case as well: I use `docker service update my_service --image my-new-image` to update some images in the swarm. Everything worked but volumes, new volumes, weren't updated. Super strange since the mysql volume was working since the beginning. I needed to stop the swarm, `docker stack rm my_swarm` and deploy again with `docker stack deploy`, which was failing until I created the folder in the host.

Answer (score 1):

try to change that to:

```
- $PWD:/var/www/:cached
```

I think you need the full path here

Comment: Just tried - same problem. It was actually mapping the full path during deployment anyway, the problem is that the path that I have locally `/home/john/valet/testapp/`. doesn't exist on remote host.

Comment: $PWD will be chnaged depend on the local directory that will not /home/john/valet/testapp/ in other places, image has nothing to do with that since volumes is a runtime directive.just make sure that you push/pull the changes in your docker-compose

Comment: why you are mounting the whole  `$PWD` in `cached` folder it is include all the folders includein what in `/php-fpm/php7.2.ini` and other locations .....

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to specify correct path for your volume. You can create a separate file and call it `docker-compose-production.yml`.

```
volumes:
  - /srv/data/www/:/var/www/
```

Also, keep in mind that for production systems you want to use `swarm` mode (`docker swarm init`) and apply stach changes with `docker swarm deploy`.

The `:cached` option is only applicable to OSX systems and most likely you are using linux-based OS in production.